# What is the exception for this error: httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found?

Tags: python, error-handling

I would like to handle the error:

"httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"

And instead just return an empty string. But I'm not sure what the except statement should be. I apologize if there is a duplicate post, but none of the posts that popped up seemed to deal with excepting this error, but rather figuring out what had gone wrong at a deeper level. I, however, just want to pass along and return an empty string.

Basically, I'm looking for what should go in the blank:

```
try:
     ....
except _____:
     ....
```

Thanks!

```
_____
```

Here is the code where the error gets thrown.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
httperror_seek_wrapper                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-181-e2b68bf19ff9> in <module>()
      5 
      6 for i in range(len(first)):
----> 7     student_html = get_stud_html(first[i],last[i],'Sophomore')
      8 #     print type(student_html)
      9 #     print parse_hfb_page(student_html)

<ipython-input-177-9b1d4294820d> in get_stud_html(first, last, year)
     60     #ideally will want to use a regex to do this in case there's more than one link on the page
     61     stud_url = 'http://facebook.college.harvard.edu/'+links_lst[12]
---> 62     stud_html = br.open(stud_url)
     63     return stud_html.get_data()
     64 

//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.pyc in open(self, url, data, timeout)
    201     def open(self, url, data=None,
    202              timeout=_sockettimeout._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
--> 203         return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
    204 
    205     def _mech_open(self, url, data=None, update_history=True, visit=None,

//anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize-0.2.5-py2.7.egg/mechanize/_mechanize.pyc in _mech_open(self, url, data, update_history, visit, timeout)
    253 
    254         if not success:
--> 255             raise response
    256         return response
    257 

httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: dunno.  Never seen it before.  What code raised it?

Comment: do you know what the type of the error is?

Answer (score 3):

That is a `urllib2.HTTPError` exception.

```
from urllib2 import HTTPError

try:
    # ...
except HTTPError:
    # ...
```

You can see this in the [source of `_mechanize.py`](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L228), where that same exception is caught and assigned to `response` to be re-raised later.